# MapMvcAttributeRoutes ignores [NonAction] attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, attributerouting

Any public method that returns `string`, `bool` or `ActionResult` in a Controller class is seen as an Action. If you want to mark it as not being an action,  you can use the `[NonAction]` attribute:

```
 [NonAction]
 public bool PubMethod(  out string param1)
 {

  return false;
 }
```

this works fine if you do not use attribute mapping routing. The app starts and the method is not seen as an action (it cannot be used as such, since it has an out param), everybody is happy.

If instead you use attribute routing:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        }
```

the `[NonAction]` attribute is ignored, and the app crashes on the line

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

complaining that the PubMethod **action** cannot be called because it has a by ref parameter.

I can't find any mention of this in the docs. Any way to mark a public method as non action when attribute routing is used?

Comment: If it is NonAction you can write it in a separate class library what problem you are facing in it.

Comment: @Saineshwar no, I can't. It is legacy code and the helper functions cannot be factored out. Anyway: I know it would be advisable to only put actions in a controller, but the problem I am discussing here is beyond the formal correctness of my code, is that an MVC attribute does not seem to work as intended.

Comment: I face the same problem. In my case I have some generic methods in a controller base class that I made public for unit testing - and MapMvcAttributeRoutes complains that it cannot route to generic methods, despite the [NonAction] attribute.